# How to solve the Ajax ScriptManager which is not visible on the AjaxControlKit

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am currently learning while developing a calendar extender using Ajax in ASP.net. Once I run the program. It keep on displaying error stated "A ScriptManager is required on the page to use ASP.NET AJAX Script Components.". Anyhow I already install Ajax Toolkit but the ScriptManager tool is not visible but other tools can be used. How to make the ScriptManager display. Kindly please help me to retrive this problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bf8LH.jpg)

Comment: `ScriptManager` control available in AJAX Extensions inside toolbox.

Comment: Thank you ya. It can works fine

Answer (score 0):

Add ScriptManager control from the toolbox. It is in the AJAX Extensions tab or you can search the toolbox to find the control.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this when the debug mode is off and aspx page is there

Do not search in ajax Specifically search in all
[image: Pic]